# fontforge package on Red Hat OpenShift

Tags: openshift, fontforge

I need to install Fontforge with my NodeJS application. How can I install it on Open Shift? from my understanding you need to use [DIY](https://developers.openshift.com/en/diy-overview.html) to install it, but i don't know so much about Unix.

Answer (score 0):

you can't install any package on you Openshift instance, but you can keep the binary in the OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR and give it execution permission